# Changing my site url from azure.net to custom domain

Tags: urls, hosting, site-url

I have created a WordPress site using Azure so when the site went live the url was `http://apidublin.azurewebsites.net/`.

I changed this to `http://www.apidublin.com/` using my domain hosting site and changing the settings on Azure.

However when I click on a post it changes back to `apidublin.azurewebsites.net` and stays like that. I know that in the general settings I shouldn't touch the wordpress url as I'm not looking to migrate the site but can I change the site url so I don't have this problem anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install "Velvet Blues Update URLs".  Add your old url in the "Old URL" field, the new one in the "New URL" field,  check all the checkboxes and click "Update URLs".  Update your permalinks afterwards

Comment: Strange, 0 urls are updated but old url is still showing up in the settings etc.. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the new URL  in **the WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** in General settings. Some of your media may be pointing your old site or may not be available in that case you need to install a plugin named [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) and you need to replace the every occurrence of the old URL with the new one.

Comment: Just be careful with search/replace - if you saved serialized data, it may break your site.

Comment: Do I use this plugin before I change the urls? I changed the Wordpress Address URL before and I wasn't able to log in afterwards.

Comment: @fischi (https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) is a great solution when dealing with serialized values